# ORO (One Reference Only) Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection

What do you think about the concept of using ORO instead of traditional Garbage Collecting? It doesn't seem to be widely adopted, and is more or less argumentative, but it can provide these benefits as I know:

- Synchronous execution of code: your program will always take known amoun of time to execute.
- Simplification of platform, you'r working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be than it development platform dependent and task dependent. So I think that ORO and GC must not be opposed, but used together - ORO for pure local object cleanup, and GC for global objects and objects, passed by reference.

Comment: Do you have an example of such GC/ORO composition?

Comment: Currently I have no any relevant example :-\